# Shortcut to enter preview mode in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

In AI, we could go to the menu "View" => "Presentation Mode" to preview entirely an artboard.

I would like to know if there is a shortcut to do that. I tried Command+Y on Mac, but it did not work.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is the default shortcut for Presentation Mode.

[image]

Comment: Shift+F doesn't do anything for me. Is this a new feature?  I'm still on AI CC2018. Hitting  F twice (without shift) toggles into full screen view though.

Comment: I added an image to the answer to show it. Not sure how new this is, i'm using the 26.5 version.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to exist in CC2018.  F alone without shift toggles these options

Comment: True, the double F used to work in older versions. Not sure when the SHIFT+F was introduced.

Comment: So now you have to do Shift+F, and then click on an option? Does F still work as a toggle between views?  Doesn't seem to be an improvement TBH.  I will never understand why Adobe has to mess with stuff that previously worked just fine.  Good to be aware of though, if I ever do upgrade eventually.

Comment: The F toggle still works as it used to, but SHIFT+F appears to be the only way to remove the interface completely AND fit the artwork to full screen. Toggling the F will remove the interface, but will not fit the artwork to screen.

Comment: I *thought* Tom may have been looking for `Trim View` in the View menu -- which is only in newer versions.

Answer (score 4):

Shortcuts are shown to the right of menu items....

[image]

If there is a shortcut for an item, it will be shown on the right.

If there's nothing to the right, you can **add your own shortcut**.

Choose `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts`, then choose `Menu Commands` from the drop down list. Find the menu with the item you want....

[image]

If the area under `Shortcut` is blank, click in that area, then type the shortcut you want.

Illustrator *will* alert you if there's a conflict or the shortcut you typed already exists.

[image]

The most difficult part is finding a key combo that is not already in use (which is why not everything has a shortcut to begin with).

---

<sub>Screenshots from a legacy version of Illustrator. Screenshots will look similar to items in newer versions, but actual content of the windows may vary slightly.</sub>